# Creating a Subdomain for an SFTP site on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, sftp, amazon-route53

I currently have an sftp site setup on AWS where I can connect via Filezilla by providing the long AWS Public DNS name or the Public IP address(hostname) along with my credentials.

I have an existing domain abc.com which is hosted elsewhere(not aws). I want to use a sub domain such as sftp.abc.com to connect to my sftp site instead of the IP address.

Can I create the subdomain(sftp.abc.com) on AWS using Route53? If so, how do I accomplish this?

Would this affect my primary domain site abc.com ?

Anyone who can give me some advice on this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: create ticket from your AWS account for better help.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hosted zone in Route 53 for the subdomain - e.g. sftp.abc.com.  Amazon will specify 4 nameservers for the hosted zone.  Simply go into your root DNS and create an NS record for the subdomain, specifying those 4 nameservers, and it should delegate authority for the subdomain to Route 53.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you response.
Would creating a sub-domain in the DNS management portal and then pointing to the AWS public IP achieve the same result as told in this article?
https://bubinga.co/pointing-subdomain-aws-ec2-instance/

Comment: It depends on what your goal is.  If your intention is to have a single site under the subdomain -- e.g. sftp.domain.com pointed at a single load balancer or instance, then the creating an A or CNAME record in your DNS management tool would be adequate.  If you are intending to have a subdomain with many endpoints and want to manage the DNS for those endpoints in AWS, then creating a true subdomain, managed in Route 53 with an NS record would be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Yep the first solution would server my purpose for now.
Thanks